# Windows 7 misses keystrokes from internal keyboard after hibernation on Acer Aspire 5820

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, hibernate, acer-aspire

After waking my computer (Acer Aspire with the factory default Windows 7 install and divers, Windows update running) from hibernation, it is a pain to type, since on average 5-10 keypresses are missing per 100 presses, using the laptop's keyboard.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Power off
2. Power on, wait for system to become usable
3. Open Notepad, for five times enter 10x the same character. This gives a similar pattern of 50 characters total:

   > xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyaaaaaaaaaassssssssssdddddddddd
4. Optionally repeat. Everything is fine this far.
5. Hibernate
6. Power on and resume
7. Repeat steps 3-4. This time approximately 3-5 character will be missing from each 50 characters

What I ruled out:

- putting to Sleep or just Locking and resuming from there does not cause problem
- <strike>battery / AC usage does not matter</strike>
- Internet connection does not matter
- running processes seem to be the same before and after hibernation
- keypress speed doesn't really matter. For the test I use a nominal 3-5 strokes/second beat.
- plugging in an external USB keyboard works fine, but the built-in one still misbehaves

What could be the problem? How could I diagnose if the keypresses arrive in, but get swallowed at some point? (maybe some nasty keyboard handler hook misbehaves?).

Pushing the PowerSmart button and toggling to power saving state fixes the problem. Also, toggling it again back to the original state keeps it fixed. So this may be a fine workaround, but is not a conforming solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `Allow hybrid sleep` to see if the problem persists?

> **Windows 7 Hibernate Problem**
>
> There are at least two different types
>   of hibernation problems. One problem
>   is that your computer is not waking up
>   properly.  Alternatively your problem
>   is there is no Hibernate option on the
>   Windows 7 Shut Down menu.  In both
>   cases check the 'Allow hybrid sleep'
>   setting.
>
> 1) For any hibernation problems the
>   easiest solution is to set 'Allow
>   hybrid sleep' to: 'Off'. (See
>   screenshot).
>
> [image: Screenshot]
>
> By design, hybrid incorporates both
>   Sleep and Hibernate, thus you only see
>   Sleep on the Shutdown menu.  Also, by
>   default, desktops are set to 'Allow
>   hybrid sleep :On'.
>
> **Trap:**  Before you can change any of
>   the Balanced settings, first you must
>   click on Change settings that are
>   currently unavailable. (See
>   screenshot)

Read more about hibernating problems [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_hibernate_problem.htm).

Comment: @ron: I didn't receive any feedback whether your problem is solved. Dis you tried my suggestion? Did you used another fix?