# ReadyBoost card "forgotten" on system resume

Tags: windows-7, readyboost

I have an SD card permanently lodged in the laptop slot to serve as ReadyBoost cache. Every now and then after resuming from hibernate/sleep i notice Windows has forgotten it was even using it before.
[image]

The old readyboost.sfcache file has to be manually deleted before telling Windows to dedicate it for ReadyBoost again. And then, it's not unusual for this laptop to recreate a new file with the *old date* of the last file.

Is this phenomenon correctable?

UPDATE

My card is formatted as exFAT (8GB). I am trying an experiment with NTFS format and observe if there is any difference.

Comment: When I've had this happen before, I've found that performing a disk scan / check for errors will usually resolve the error, and allow ReadyBoost to be enabled again; but then I'm not sure about the "left over" file you're reporting in my cases, so it might be a different cause. Try that anyway and see what happens (after all, there's not harm in letting Windows check that your SD card is in working order).

Comment: The thing with the *old* date has to do with [tunneling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/15/439261.aspx).

Comment: Interesting explanation, Mehrdad, but i only seem to observe this tunneling happening on just this system; it also happens on a .png that i save overwrite over and over again. However, i've never witnessed this in any other system; how can i set this feature explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, that formatting the memory card with **NTFS instead of exFAT** improves the "grip" reliability Windows has on the card across system sleep cycles.

Not only does Windows remember its use of ReadyBoost, i can also observe readyboost.sfcache being updated and modified date changed per wake.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the hybrid sleep option as shown [on this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/246962/windows-7-misses-keystrokes-from-internal-keyboard-after-hibernation-on-acer-asp/246985#246985). This answer was answered for another question but the hybrid sleep solution might help you.

Please, let me know whether it helped, if it doesn't I can help finding another solution for your problem.